# ajax listener for file uploading progress

Tags: javascript

I cant find a way to get around my code. I have seen some tutorials out there, but because of the way I design my code I guess I need something different.

```
 (function(){
    var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');

    var uploadFile = function (files) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var i;

        var file_size = 0;
        for(i = 0; i<files.length; i = i+1){
            formData.append('file[]', files[i]);
            file_size = file_size + files[i].size;
        }
        request.onload = function(){
            var data = this.responseText;
           // window.location.reload();
        };
        request.open('post', 'dragNdrop.php?isNotSet=set');
        request.send(formData);
    };

    dropzone.ondragover = function(){
        this.className = 'dropzone dragover';
        return false;
    };

    dropzone.ondragleave = function(){
        this.className = 'dropzone';
        return false;
    };

    dropzone.ondrop = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.className = 'dropzone';
        uploadFile(event.dataTransfer.files);
        return false;
    }
}());
```

This is the code I use to upload a file, but i cant find a way to add a eventlistener that keeps checking if the file has been uploaded. I have tried.

```
request.upload = function(){console.log("me")} //Returns nothing
```

I tried something like this:

```
request.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressBar, false);

 function progressBar(event){
     var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
     console.log(percent + " " + event.loaded + " " + event.total);
 }
```

It only returns the value once, I would imagine it needs to return several times as it needs to loop in order to get the progress bar moving?

All this function below was inside the main function.

How else could I do this?

Comment: http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/.

Comment: That uses jquery I want plain javascript

Comment: It uses `vanilla Javascript` in `jQuery`. U can use it. Look at the `XHR` example.

Comment: OK thanks will check it out